Remove prefix from Docker ENV variable and create a new variable
I´m currently building a dockerfile base on Amazonlinux2 and trying to remove a prefix from an environment variable in order to use it for other operations later one.
# renovate: datasource=github-tags depName=apache/maven
ENV MAVEN_VERSION=maven-3.9.5
ENV MAVEN_CLEAN_VERSION=${MAVEN_VERSION/maven-/}  

I need the maven- in my first variable otherwise my renovate bot doesn't find the right version of maven in github. I cannot make this `MAVEN_VERSION="maven-3.9.5", because of the same reason.
For further processes I want a clean version like 3.9.5.
Currently not able to get this working, running the code shown above, results in:
Step 17/47 : ENV MAVEN_CLEAN_VERSION=${MAVEN_VERSION#maven-}
failed to process "${MAVEN_VERSION#maven-}": missing ':' in substitution

In my local bash it is working, but I think there is some special Docker stuff that I´m currently not aware of.
Thanks for any help!

I would try to save to variable on tmp file, with that way the variable will not be lost betwen to docker commands.
try these lines below
RUN echo "export MAVEN_CLEAN_VERSION=`${MAVEN_VERSION#maven-}`" >> /envfile
RUN . /envfile; echo $MAVEN_CLEAN_VERSION

To use the variable you need to run /envfile before, this will upload the variable again.
